# Using a manipulated property on all of the functions in a class (python)

Tags: python, oop

I'm looking for the best way to solve a scenario I encountered.
I have a python class that gets as one of its properties a string, that represents the absolute path of a file in the filesystem.
In all of the functions where the property is used, I convert the string to a list that every item on the list is a directory in the mentioned path.
Obviously I don't want to create the list every time I need to use it, because it's much more sensible to have an attribute in the class that is that list. But I don't want to put that logic in the constructor, because it's bad practice to have anything but assignments in the constructor (testing wise, although this is not that bad of a case).
How would you handle this? Where would you put such a property in the class if you didn't want to recalculate it everytime you use it?

Comment: Why do you think it's bad practice to have something other than a field assignment in a constructor?

Comment: "It's bad practice to have anything but assignments in the constructor": who told you that? Avoiding side effects and I/O is sensible, but massaging data from one format to another is also perfectly sensible.

Comment: Alex Reinking I'm just used to constructors having no logic other than the assignments. Perhaps I'm wrong, but that appears to be the pattern in most of the classes I've encountered. Not only in Python

Comment: For *some* classes it makes sense for `__init__` to do nothing but make assignments; Python 3.7's `dataclass` decorator makes defining such classes simpler.

Comment: @Hollevan - it is always preferable to guarantee that objects are in a well-defined state post-construction (and always remain so). To that end most OOP language libraries will perform validation on their constructor arguments and might even throw exceptions!

Comment: chepner sadly we're using Python 3.6. So close though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Put it in the constructor.

Not only could your code suffer performance-wise from potentially hundreds of list allocations and string manipulations, but you're bound to introduce a *ton* of code duplication at the beginnings of functions. There's no edict that says *thou shalt recompute derived properties on every function call*.

Write it like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.original_path = path
        self._split_path = MyClass.split(path) # or whatever the function is called

    def my_method(self):
        # use self._split_path here.
        pass
```

Comment: I'm glad that's the answer. I learned something and earned an easy solution!